# Generating a list of numbers without repeating digits

Tags: algorithm

I'm attempting to generate an ascending list of numbers that do not have repeating digits (e.g.1234) as part of a school computing project.

I want to use the algorithm to generate lists that follow that rule for 8 digits and have been using the following algorithms:

- Generating all numbers then removing the ones with repeated digits - this ends up creating 8^8 numbers which takes too long
- Generating random numbers that follow the rule and then seeing if I have generated them already - this has much less numbers to create (8!) however the odds of finding a new number when there are few left becomes very slim.

I need to use a different algorithm for this but I can't figure out what. What would be the best algorithm to do this?

Comment: Just add the last obtained number to the next random one.

Comment: What do you mean by "last obtained number"?

Comment: Generate the n+1st number by adding the nth number to a random strictly positive number, thus each new number is strictly greater than the preceding one, and therefore they are all different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't want to say too much, but you don't want to check anything. It would be better if the algorithm could always produce a correct answer. Have you considered generating them by taking 1 digit at a time from the set of unselected digits? And you don't have to find all the arrangements because there is a simple combinatorics function to find that.  (Just remember to eliminate leading zero except for "0")

Comment: I think I've explained this badly. I know how to generate one of these numbers. I'm struggling with making a list of all of them between 0 and n.

Comment: If you do what Kenny outlines here and your source list of digits is in ascending order then the resulting numbers will also be in ascending order.

Comment: But you don't have to generate them in numerical order.  You can generate them in some other order that's guaranteed to be right and get all of them.  And it's not some fancy math thing, it's just common sense.  Basically take each digit once.  Darnit, I said too much ;)

Comment: (and then have another function to generate all permutations of that set of digits)

Comment: I'm still confused on the process that you are following sorry. So say I have an array of 8 values listed 0-8 and I take them out one by one removing them from the array as I do so to form the first number, how do I then get the second?

Comment: Now that you said the word permutations, I've found an online generator which will do the job. This is above my head so I think I will leave it. Thanks for the help.